# How to convert from linalg.Vector to regression.Labeledpoint format?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

So I was trying to implement a simple machine learning code in the spark-shell and when I tried to give the a csv file, it demanded a libsvm format, so I used the [phraug](https://github.com/zygmuntz/phraug) library to convert my dataset into the required format. While that worked, I also needed to normalize my data, so I used [Standard Scaler](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#standardscalerhttp://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#standardscaler) to transform the data. That also worked fine, The next step was to train the machine and for that I used the SVMWithSGD model. But when I tried to train I kept getting the error

```
    error: type mismatch;
    found: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Double,org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)]
    required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint]
```

I understand that it is a compatibility issue, and the Vector.dense function can be used,but I don't want to split it again and what I don't understand is, isn't there a direct method so that I can use it for the train method?
P.S. To help you understand the data currently looks like this

```
    (0.0,[0.03376345160534202,-0.6339809012492886,-6.719697792783955,-6.719697792783965,-6.30231507117855,-8.72828614492483,0.03884804438718658,0.3041969425433718])
    (0.0,[0.2535328275090413,-0.8780294632355746,-6.719697792783955,-6.719697792783965,-6.30231507117855,-8.72828614492483,0.26407233411369857,0.3041969425433718])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `RDD[Double, Vector]` is called `vectorRDD`:

```
val labeledPointRDD = vectorRDD map { 
  case (label, vector) => LabeledPoint(label, vector) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nedim You are a life saver. It is almost embarrassing how long I spent on this problem and how simple the solution was. I would like to ask another question, Will this in any way effect the speed/optimization of the program because currently I am working on a smaller data set but I plan to move to a bigger one in the future using the same piece of code?

Comment: `map` has roughly O(n) complexity. Construction of a `LabeledPoint` is a relatively cheap operation. This code scales well with the size of the data.